# Why are my keys being overwritten when inserting an object into a map?

Tags: c++, object, dictionary

I am running into the problem of when inserting elements into a map, I assume that every time I put a new object into it, the previous one is overwritten. Whenever I go to print out the contents of my map, only the most recent item I added is printed. I have two  classes, a Recipe class and an Ingredient class. My recipe has a `map<Ingredient*, int>` which holds and object and its quantity.

```
Recipe::Recipe(){
    title = "";
    ingredients;
}

void Recipe::insertIngredient(Ingredient* item, int quantity){
    ingredients.insert( make_pair( item, quantity  ) );
}

Ingredient::Ingredient(){
    name = "";
    unit = "";
}
```

I have getters and setters for each class that I use to initialize variables and to print out the contents, but whenever I print the contents of my Recipe's map only the last item I put into it is printed out. The following is in my main function to print out the map.

```
map<Ingredient*, int> tempIngredients = tempRecipe->getIngredients();

map<Ingredient*, int>::iterator ingredientIt;

for (ingredientIt = tempIngredients.begin(); ingredientIt!= tempIngredients.end();    ingredientIt++) {
    Ingredient* tempIngredient  = ingredientIt->first;
    int quantity = ingredientIt->second;
    cout << "\n" << tempIngredient->getName() << " " << tempIngredient->getUnit() << " " <<  quantity << flush;
}
```

My output is currently the following:

unbleached wheat blend flour C. 1

Which is the igredient's name, unit, and quantity(value from the map) of the last element I added.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a pointer for the map key without implementing a comparison operator.

You would be much better off using an `Ingredient` object and implement `operator<`.

For example,

```
class Ingredient {
    public:
        bool operator<(const Ingredient & b) const {
            return getName() < b.getName();
        }

    // Rest of class methods data etc...
};

std::map<Ingredient, int> ingredients;
```

Comment: Doing this I receive the error passing ‘const Ingredient’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::string Ingredient::getName()’ discards qualifiers

Comment: You need to add a `const` version of get name.  `const std::string & getName() const { return ... }`

Comment: I added `const string & getName() const {
    return name;
}` and the same error was given. I changed my Ingredients from pointers to objects, was that needed?

Comment: You want to use objects instead of pointers.  Are you sure the error was the same?

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling `insertIngredient`?  Since your map is keyed by `Ingredient*`, each entry must be a unique `Ingredient` object (by new or off the stack) or the keys will clash.

The real question is why are you keying on a pointer?  Per @GWW's answer, a better solution would be to store `Ingredient` values and create a custom comparator function for them.

Comment: From my main I have `tempRecipe->insertIngredient(tempIngredient->iterateIngredients(ingredient), quantity);` which parses an XML file for the ingredient and its quantity.